# Write mongodb mapReduce result to a file

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDb where data in the collection has the following structure :

```
{userid = 1 (the id of the user), key1 = value1 , key2 = value2, .... }
```

I want to write mongodb mapreduce functions where i could put the userid in the map function and in the reduce function i need to write they ( key,value ) pairs in a csv (?) file such that they would be :

key1,key2, key3,...

value1,value2,value3,..

value1,value2,value3,..

value1,value2,value3,..

How can i do that with mongodb

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "file output" option.

The MongoDB documentation has details on [exporting data](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools).

In particular, `mongoexport` allows for export by JSON or CSV which should be legible from other software.

If you want to significantly modify the data output, then you'll have to use a client library and cursor through the data while writing to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can not write data to a file directly. You have to implement such a functionality on the application level by reading the data from the collection and writing it to the filesystem in whatever format.

Comment: Thanks, one other question if you know, each userid, has a different set of key/value pairs, how do i write my emit to be generic.. so that it goes through they key1=value1, key2=value2, etc.. .. so it would be something like : emit(this.userid, *the rest of the key/value pairs would go here ) ;

Comment: Don't use comments for new questions. And accept the answer if it works for you.